# most efficient way to parse a string using c++ features

Tags: c++, string, parsing

this might be a stupid question (I hope not) but it caught my mind and I'm trying to figure it out. What is the most efficient way to parse a string using c++ features? 
I appreciate everyone's comments as I, am I'm sure everyone else is too, to become a better programmer!
Here is how I would do it right now with my current knowledge:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::cout;
using std::string;
using std::endl;
void parseLine(string &line)
{
    constexpr char DELIMITER_ONE = '|';
    constexpr char DELIMITER_TWO = '[';
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
    {
        if (line[i] == DELIMITER_ONE || line[i] == DELIMITER_TWO)
        {
            line.erase(i, 1);
        }
    }
    cout << line << endl;
}
int main()
{
    std::string testString = "H|el[l|o|";
    parseLine(testString);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work correctly if there are two delimiters in a row (unless it is your intention to leave one of them in the string).

Comment: http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/recursive-descent-peg-parsers-using-c-te/212700432

Comment: Are you sure? it works on my machine. those are l's not the vertical bar.

Comment: Yes, the function works for the single test case you are exercising it with. Should you try to call `parseLine` on a string that does, in fact, contain two vertical bars in a row, the outcome might surprise you.

Answer (score 5):

```
line.erase(
    std::remove_if(line.begin(), line.end(),
        [](char c) { return c == DELIMITER_ONE || c == DELIMITER_TWO; }
    ),
    line.end()
);
```

See also: [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom)

Answer (score 0):

One more way is to use the boost regex library. Check the below code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

int main(){
  std::string testString = "H|el[l|o|";
  boost::regex rx("\\||\\[");
  std::string replace = "";
  std::string out = boost::regex_replace(testString, rx, replace);
  std::cout << out << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C++14 now includes regular expressions standard:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

std::string parseLine(const std::string& line);

int main() {
    std::string testString = "H|el[l|o|";
    std::string result = parseLine(testString);
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

std::string parseLine(const std::string& line) {

    std::string input_string;
    std::string result;

    std::smatch sm;
    std::regex r("([a-zA-Z]+)");

    for(input_string = line; std::regex_search(input_string, sm, r); input_string = sm.suffix()) {
        result.append(sm[0].str());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is less efficient however.

Comment: @NeilKirk I guess you could use Nipun's answer using the C++14 `std::regex_replace` function, but I wouldn't know if it's any more efficient than mine.

Comment: Igor Tandetnik's answer is the most efficient.